# Laravel 8 how to show & hide or grayed out Div when another Div Dropdown selection value of foreignkey from different table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-8

I want to show & hide or grayed out Text forms based on the Another Div dropdown selection and this dropdown selection is foreignkey element from different table.

> attendance_type
> table will have AB \ PR values respectively

**This is my dropdown blade code**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="attendance_type_id">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.attendance_type') }}</label>
                <select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('attendance_type') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="attendance_type_id" id="attendance_type_id">
                    @foreach($attendance_types as $id => $entry)
                        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('attendance_type_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $entry }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('attendance_type'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('attendance_type') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.attendance_type_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
```

When i select the AB value selected then following should be displayed or grayed out from editing and if select PR value from the attendance_type table following div code should be displayed!

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="in_time">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.in_time') }}</label>
                <input class="form-control timepicker {{ $errors->has('in_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="in_time" id="in_time" value="{{ old('in_time') }}">
                @if($errors->has('in_time'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('in_time') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.in_time_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="out_time">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.out_time') }}</label>
                <input class="form-control timepicker {{ $errors->has('out_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="out_time" id="out_time" value="{{ old('out_time') }}">
                @if($errors->has('out_time'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('out_time') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.out_time_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hey, I only see PHP code, while you would need JS to perform this task. This is one of the reasons I find Vue.js more handy than blade: You still build the template in a similar way, but it is reactive.

Comment: HI @RobBiermann thanks for reply! Definitely gonna try Vue.js!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Blade Code**

```
<div class="form-group" id="InTime_dis">
                <label for="in_time">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.in_time') }}</label>
                <input class="form-control timepicker {{ $errors->has('in_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="in_time" id="in_time" value="{{ old('in_time') }}">
                @if($errors->has('in_time'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('in_time') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.in_time_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="OutTime_dis">
                <label for="out_time">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.out_time') }}</label>
                <input class="form-control timepicker {{ $errors->has('out_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="out_time" id="out_time" value="{{ old('out_time') }}">
                @if($errors->has('out_time'))
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{ $errors->first('out_time') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.attendance.fields.out_time_helper') }}</span>
            </div>
```

**My JsScript Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#attendance_type_id').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == '2')
    {
      $("#InTime_dis").show();
      $("#OutTime_dis").show();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#InTime_dis").hide();
      $("#OutTime_dis").hide();
     }
  });
});

</script>
```

Hope this might help laravel beginners!